# Get all files created in past 24 hours - unix

Tags: unix

How can I load all the files created in last 24 hours from a server X to server Y through a script (both being linux servers)?

I do know that the command `find . -mtime -1 -exec cp '{}' <new_dir>` would copy all the files in current directory to . But I am not sure how to do this for a  located on another server.

Comment: Run `find` on the other server instead of in `.` on the local machine?

Comment: `-mtime` finds modified files, not created files. There's a difference. What you're looking for sounds like `rsync`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at `rsync`.  It could be a good match for your needs.

Answer (score 1):

Just replace cp with scp and set up an ssh key pair without a passphrase.